# JS: Image upload live manipulation, scale, dimensions and crop

Tags: javascript, jquery, image, gd

I am creating a CMS which has a number of images which a user can upload and attach to various places in the pages.

I am trying to find a nice, preferably jquery based plugin or similar for scaling an image before allowing it to be cropped.

I have implemented jCrop http://deepliquid.com/content/Jcrop.html which is working great. However a user, if they upload a large image, cannot scale the image down in order to then crop a section of it.

I understand that it's possible using GD to scale the image down, but it would be ace to combine scale and crop functionality in the javascript interface in order to give the use a better idea of what they are doing to the image before they save it.

If I create a custom function to change the height and width of an image perhaps tied to a slider control, will I be able to pass the data into GD lib? So that I can drop and scale all in one go before outputting the new adjusted image?

Answer (score 0):

If you can mandate that HTML5 capable browsers be used, this project might solve all of your problems:
http://hacks.mozilla.org/2010/02/an-html5-offline-image-editor-and-uploader-application/